# How to generate RSA-SHA256 digital signature with OpenSSL libraries?

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, digital-signature, sha256

I need to generate a digital signature from C++ code, using OpenSSL libraries.
I understood that I need for that DSA \ DSA_do_sign, but didn't understand how exactly to use it.

Does someone have an example for that, or a reference for better than OpenSSL's supplied docs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have RSA and DSA confused. However, if you want to sign using RSA-sha256, then use the [EVP interface for signing](http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_SignInit.html#). You can initialize with the `EVP_SignInit_ex()` method with `EVP_sha256()` for the `type` argument.